# Configuring dfmt to allow one element per line

Tags: visual-studio-code, d

With dfmt, the source code formatter for D language, the following code:

```
auto carModels = [
    "alpha", 
    "bravo", 
    "charlie", 
    "delta"
];
```

gets re-formatted into:

`auto carModels = ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta"];`

Is there a way to make the formatter keep the elements one per line as specified in the original, without turning off dfmt for that line?

I am using the vs-code D language extension called code-d, it invokes dfmt when formatting files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been added to dfmt with a new flag called `keep_line_breaks`

https://github.com/dlang-community/dfmt/pull/471